# create a css Display:block that is right-to-left

Tags: css, right-to-left

i created a list of items using a display:block css propery.

the display:block property created a list of items in english that are left-to-right.
i translated the items to Hebrew, which is right-to-left but the text stays on the left.
i need to make the display:block text stick to the right side (right-to-left).
i tried:

direction:rtl;
text-align:right
and even float:right 
nothing effect the display:block.

as you can see in the example the list stick to the left and ignores the above properties i added:

[image]

how can i make a disply:block have text right-to-left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `text-align: right` setting is sufficient, but in your code, some part (not visible in the screen shot) overrides it somehow, either on the `ul` element or on the inner `li` elements.

Comment: it was another css that override my ui , exactly as you said! thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

CSS has multilingual support for RTL-Languages with the  `direction` property. Use the value `ltr` (latin) or `rtl` (Hebrew). Any other properties should be superfluous, especially the `text-align`. Does removing it help? It should be script-direction dependent: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Comment: thanks amon, becuase your comment i rechecked the text-align:right on display"block without my specific code and it does work. which means that the problem is specificlly in my code..... what can prevent it from being aligned?.....

Comment: The `rtr` just inverses the meaning of `right` and `left` in the `text-align`-property. Start thinking of them as "primary" and "secondary" margin. In your case `direction:rtl; text-align:left;` is completely sufficient. You can remove the `float` property.